# How to write a sparse matrix to file as text using scala/breeze?

Tags: scala, matrix, save, apache-spark, breeze

I'm new to scala and breeze. Please forgive this question if the answer is obvious. I cannot figure out how to write a sparse matrix to file. Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

```
import breeze.linalg.CSCMatrix

val B = CSCMatrix.zeros[Int](4,4)
B(0,2) = 1
```

Now, I want to save B to file as text.

I've thought about mapping the elements of B to a string and then writing to file but that seems wrong. Also, I can convert it to a dense matrix and write it to file but that also seems wrong. Interestingly, even if I do convert it to a dense matrix it will still have to be of type Doubles before csvwrite will work. Arg...please save me from spark/scala hell.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [csvwrite](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/blob/master/math/src/main/scala/breeze/linalg/package.scala#L83) which accepts Matrix[Double].

```
import java.io.File
import breeze.linalg.{CSCMatrix, csvwrite}


val B = CSCMatrix.zeros[Double](4,4)
B(0, 2) = 1.0
csvwrite(new File("myCSCMatrix.txt"), B, separator=' ')
```

Comment: As per the [wiki](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/wiki/Linear-Algebra-Cheat-Sheet) Breeze currently supports IO of matrices in 2 ways 1. Java serialization and 2. Csv. Now, with csvwrite using a Matrix of type Double and then writing to file seems to be the only workaround as pointed by @Eshan M. Kermani